# Meteor reactivity in functions, return session.get('variable'), runs everytime session.set('variable') is run?

Tags: meteor

Ok, let's say I have a client side function that returns a Session variable, eg:

```
Template.hello.random = function() {
  return Session.get('variable');
};
```

Somewhere else let's say I have a button that does

```
Session.set('variable', random_number);
```

Everytime I hit that button, will my Template.hello.random function run? I find it hard to wrap my head around that..

Comment: yes it does. What about it?

Comment: _why_ does it do that?

Answer (score 4):

All the Meteor "Magic" comes from `Deps.Dependency` and `Deps.Computation` (http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency)

eg

```
var weather = "sunny";
var weatherDep = new Deps.Dependency;

var getWeather = function () {
  weatherDep.depend()
  return weather;
};

var setWeather = function (w) {
  weather = w;
  // (could add logic here to only call changed()
  // if the new value is different from the old)
  weatherDep.changed();
};
```

`Session` mirror's this pattern, but as a key/value store instead of just one value. (Actually `Session` is just an instance of the [`ReactiveDict` class](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js))

When you have a computation that calls `getWeather()` the `.depend()` call links it to the computation - and the `.changed()` call `invalidates` that computation.

eg, getting a computation via `Deps.autorun()`

```
computaton = Deps.autorun(function(){
  var localWeather = getWeather();
  console.log("local weather", localWeather);
});
computation.onInvalidate(function(){ 
  console.log("a dependency of this computation changed");
});
console.log("setting  weather");
setWeather("abc");
```

With this infrastructure - we find out that `Template` helpers are run in a computation - and when the dependencies of the computation are `.changed()`, it queues up the template to re-render.

Comment: so Deps.Dependency and Deps.Computation is happening under the covers?

Comment: Yep! the best part about Meteor is that it's open-source, and it's just written in plain javascript. If you're curious go over to their github repo (https://github.com/meteor/meteor) and poke around!